# Usage of Where error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm new at MsSql.

My SQl comand is

```
EXEC('SELECT '+@columnnames +' From WindData Where 
  (TimeStamp between '''+@startdate+''' and '''+@finishdate+''') 
and (DATEPART(second,TimeStamp) = ''00'') 
and (DATEPART(minute,TimeStamp) = ''15'' 
    or DATEPART(minute,TimeStamp) = ''30'' 
    or DATEPART(minute,TimeStamp) = ''45'' 
    or DATEPART(minute,TimeStamp) = ''00''
    ) 
order by TimeStamp')
```

My Sql Query is not working. I think I dont use right and or conjunction.
Please help me.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @rontornambe it return 0. but proper data is in my database.

Comment: What is it you want to see?

Comment: I suggest baby steps.  Start by selecting * from WindData where 1=2.  Then add the @columnnames variable.  Then keep building your query bit by bit until you discover the part that throws the error, or until it's done.

Comment: what is the condition you are checking in where condition.. is there any column with name 'TimeStamp' in you WindData table?

Comment: Note that `DATEPART` returns an integer, so you don't need those quotes around the values.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. Please post sample data and the values of `@startdate` and `@enddate`

Comment: Instead EXEC use PRINT('...') and post the result.